# Google Sign-in and Spring Security

Tags: authentication, jsf, spring-security, google-signin

I am ashamed to admit that I burned four full days trying to get Spring Security 3.1 to play nicely with Google Sign-in in a standard JSF web application. Both are awesome frameworks in their own right but they seemed incompatible. I finally got it to work in some fashion but strongly suspect that I have missed some fundamental concept and am not doing it the best way.

I am writing an app that our helpdesk uses to track system testing during maintenance activities when our systems are down and cannot host the app, so it is hosted externally. Our Active Directory and IdP are down during this activity so I cannot use our normal authentication systems. Google Sign-in is a perfect solution for this.

Google Sign-in works great in the browser using Google Javascript libraries and some simple code. The browser communicates with Google to determine if the user is already signed in, and if not, opens a separate window where the user can submit credentials and authenticate. Then a small bit of Javascript can send a concise, ephemeral id_token returned from Google to the server which the server can use to verify the authentication independently with Google. That part was easy. The beauty is that if the user is already signed into Gmail or some other Google app, authentication has already happened and Google does not challenge the user again.

Spring Security works great on the server side to protect specified resources and authenticate a user with a username and password. However, in this case, we never see the username or password - the credentials are protected by secure communication between the browser and Google. All we know is whether or not the user is authenticated. We can get the Google username, but Spring Security expects credentials that it can use to authenticate, to a database, in-memory user base, or any other system. It is not, to my knowledge, compatible with another system that simply provides yea-or-nay authentication in the browser.

I found many good examples online that use Spring Boot with EnableOAuth2Sso (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727014/spring-boot-spring-security-spring-oauth2-google-sign-in)) but surprisingly few that use Spring Security in a standard app server which does not support EnableOAuth2Sso, and those few did not show any solution I could discern.

Here is how I've done it. I followed Google's simple directions [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) to provide authentication in the browser. I added this code to the onSignIn() method to send the id_token to the server.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Trigger an authentication for Spring security
        xhr.open("POST", "/<my app context>/j_spring_security_check", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        var params = "profileID=" + profile.getId() + "&amp;fullname=" +  profile.getName() + "&amp;email=" + profile.getEmail() + "&amp;id_token=" + googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token
            + "&amp;j_username=" + profile.getEmail() + "&amp;j_password=" + id_token;
        xhr.send(params);
        window.location.replace("/<my app context>/index.xhtml");
```

Unfortunately the Spring Authentication object, when passed to the AuthenticationProvider that I provided, did not contain anything but the j_username and j_password parameters as Authentication.getPrincipal() and Authentication.getCredentials(), but this is all I really needed. This is a bit of an abuse of those parameters since I have set them to email and id_token, not username and password.

I wanted to pass the user's full name and email, which Google provides in Javascript as googleUser.getName() and googleUser.getEmail(), to the backend as well. Since Spring Security does not accommodate anything but the username/password, and I was using Primefaces/JSF, I used Primefaces RemoteCommand to call a method on the backing bean with this information. This also feels a little clumsy.

In addition, I had to use window.location.replace() (in code above) because Spring Security did not redirect to my index.xhtml page as expected when I set this in the context with:

```
<security:form-login login-page='/login.xhtml' authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml?error=true" default-target-url="/index.html" always-use-default-target="true" />
```

I have no idea why this does not work.

However, the app does now behave as I want in that it authenticates the user and the authenticated user can access the resources specified in Spring Security, and I wanted to share this in case anyone is doing a similar thing. Can anyone suggest a cleaner/better way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this JSF related? I only see spring and google related things

Comment: Good question, thanks, I left this out. The Google Sign-in documentation uses an XMLHttpRequest to a servlet to pass the id_token to the backend from the browser. JSF encapsulates servlets, which further complicated things, so I did this with Primefaces' RemoteCommand and I wanted to share that. I've edited the post to add this.